# Create a personalised download link

Tags: php, html, security

If i have items stored in a database that users can download after they purchase, how can I provide a link that is different on a per user basis?

I was thinking, would the correct thing to do be: give them a link that is hashed in some way based on their user id for example.Then, when i process the link i have given them i just reverse the hash function to get the original link. Is this the correct way of doing things?

If this is not the correct approach could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash functions are not meant to be reversed. I would suggest to read about lighttpd [`mod_secdownload`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-mod_secdownload-configuration.html) implementation

It gives you a protected link, valid for a certain amount of time. Because a hash cannot be reversed, you need to pass a hash of your information along with the clear text information (if possible) in the link. Ex:

```
http://somesite.com/download.php?hash=<md5($secretkey.$userId.$documentId)>&usrId=<$userId>&documentId=<$documentId>
```

When you receive a request to download, process the has, compare it to the given one, if it's equal then you consider it verified.

Answer (score 0):

You should store in your database something like "download tokens". When a user wants to download something, you create a new token (a random number for example), and if there are multiple things to be downloaded, you can bind it to them with their ID for example.

In the URL simple send the token as a GET variable. Once the user downloads the content, delete the token from the database.